# Why do i need to add transaction in this?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, transactions

Why do we need to always Start  a transaction in hibernate to save,insert,delete or update?

Is the auto commit feature by default false in hibernate?

like for this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("creating empopbjects");
        emp e1=new emp("a","x",1234);
        emp e2=new emp("b","y",324);
        emp e3=new emp("c","z",23345);
        System.out.println("saving emp objects..");
        Session s=myfactory.getsession();
        s.save(e1);
        s.save(e2);
        s.save(e3);
        s.close();
        System.out.println("successfully saved");
    }
```

This wont save anything whereas if i add Transaction then only it is added?why so?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("creating empopbjects");
        emp e1=new emp("a","x",1234);
        emp e2=new emp("b","y",324);
        emp e3=new emp("c","z",23345);
        System.out.println("saving emp objects..");
        Session s=myfactory.getsession();
        Transaction t =s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(e1);
        s.save(e2);
        s.save(e3);
        t.commit();
        s.close();
        System.out.println("successfully saved");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well defined answer of your question from [one of the SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931162/will-hibernate-flush-my-updated-persistent-object-when-calling-session-close-w) is here.

> Look at the following code, which
>   accesses the database without
>   transaction boundaries:
>
> ```
> Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
> session.get(Item.class, 123l); 
> session.close();
> ```
>
> By default, in a Java SE environment
>   with a JDBC configuration, this is
>   what happens if you execute this
>   snippet:
>
> 1. A new Session is opened. It doesn’t obtain a database connection at this
>      point.
> 2. The call to get() triggers an SQL SELECT. The Session now obtains a JDBC
>      Connection from the connection pool.
>      Hibernate, by default, immediately
>      turns off the autocommit mode on this
>      connection with setAutoCommit(false).
>      This effectively starts a JDBC
>      transaction!
> 3. The SELECT is executed inside this JDBC transaction. The Session is
>      closed, and the connection is returned
>      to the pool and released by Hibernate
>      — Hibernate calls close() on the JDBC
>      Connection. What happens to the
>      uncommitted transaction?
>
> The answer to that question is, “It
>   depends!” The JDBC specification
>   doesn’t say anything about pending
>   transactions when close() is called on
>   a connection. What happens depends on
>   how the vendors implement the
>   specification. With Oracle JDBC
>   drivers, for example, the call to
>   close() commits the transaction! Most
>   other JDBC vendors take the sane route
>   and roll back any pending transaction
>   when the JDBC Connection object is
>   closed and the resource is returned to
>   the pool.
>
> Obviously, this won’t be a problem for
>   the SELECT you’ve executed, but look
>   at this variation:
>
> ```
> Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
> Long generatedId = session.save(item); 
> session.close();
> ```
>
> This code results in an INSERT
>   statement, executed inside a
>   transaction that is never committed or
>   rolled back. On Oracle, this piece of
>   code inserts data permanently; in
>   other databases, it may not. (This
>   situation is slightly more
>   complicated: The INSERT is executed
>   only if the identifier generator
>   requires it. For example, an
>   identifier value can be obtained from
>   a sequence without an INSERT. **The
>   persistent entity is then queued until
>   flush-time insertion — which never
>   happens in this code**. An identity
>   strategy requires an immediate INSERT
>   for the value to be generated.)

Bottom line: use explicit transaction demarcation.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Session is a [Unit of Work](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/), and queries are only executed during flush time (which may occur prior to executing any query, or when your currently executing Transaction is committed).

Auto-commit is only meaningful in SQL consoles and it's undesirable in Enterprise applications. When using an ORM tool, you are managing Entity object state transitions rather than executing DML operations. It's only at the flush time, when state transitions are translated to DML operations.

So, while you can write JDBC statements in auto-commit, JPA doesn't allow you to do so.