# why `EntityManager` work,but EntityManagerFactory did not work for me?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I try to use `Spring+JPA+Hibernat`e and try to inject `EntityManagerFactory`,and  later create EntityManger in my code.But when I use `entityManager.persist(user)`,the `user` not saving to the `database`.But when I try to inject the `EntityManager` instead of `EntityManagerFactory`,it worked !,I do not know where is the problem.

you can also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053071/entitymanager-persist-not-saving-anything-to-database/37117342#37117342) for more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a plain `EntityManagerFactory` instead of an `EntityManager` you need to call `createEntityManager`. This will always create a new `EntityManager`, this is basically a plain `EntityManager` not managed nor detected by Spring. So you will also have to start/commit transactions yourself.

When using the `EntityManager` you will obtain a transactional synchronized instance, which is managed by Spring and bound to the current transaction. So no need to start / commit a transaction yourself.

See also the [JPA section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) of the reference guide.