# Hibernate does not save Object even not getting any error in log

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, spring-annotations

I have a single table in db . Created a pojo class to map class instance to table. my class structure is

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "example")
    class example {
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        int id;
        @Column(name = "SLOT_ID")
        int slot_id;
        @Column(name = "SLOT_DATE")
        String slot_date;
        @Column(name = "HOTEL_ID")
        String hotel_id;
        @Column(name = "ROOM_TYPE_ID")
        String room_type_id;
        @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
        String create_date;
        @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
        String update_date;
        @Column(name = "SLOT_PRICE")
        Double slot_price;
        @Column(name = "AVAILABLE_ROOMS")
        Integer available_roooms;

//rest have getter and setter method }
```

Hibernet commit part

```
  public void save(Example example) {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            log.info( example.toString());
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(example);
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

in log i am getting this log

```
Hibernate: insert into example(AVAILABLE_ROOMS, CREATE_DATE, HOTEL_ID, ROOM_TYPE_ID, SLOT_DATE, SLOT_ID, SLOT_PRICE, UPDATE_DATE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I am able to fetch data from same table here is Code snap `

```
session = this.sessionFactory.openSession(); 
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Example.class); cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)); List results = cr.list();
 if(results.size()>0) 
return mapper.writeValueAsString(results.get(0)); //id is auto //incremented in table`
```

I dont see any error in log but when i cheked in DB no data has been inserted.Any clue what i missed ?

Comment: How are you creating your session factory?

Comment: Hi John, i have defined session factory as a bean then it autowired with implmentation      @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
I have checked , i am getting instance of sessionFactory

Comment: Hi John, I am able  to fetch data from same table here is Code snap session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Example.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
            List results = cr.list();
            if(results.size()>0)
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(results.get(0));                //id is auto //incremented in table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code and test once

```
public void save(Example example) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx=null;
    try {
        log.info( example.toString());
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(example);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

     if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {
     tx.rollback();
     }//not much doing but a good practice
     session.flush(); //this is where I think things will start working.
     session.close();
    }
}
```

Good reason to call flush before close is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969109/why-hibernate-session-close-does-not-flushes-the-data-automatically)

Comment: Hi Viraj , I have tried but it didn't work. I try also try one more thing is . create a new table without any auto inremented field and then insert dummy data (Hibernate: insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)
) . I cheked insertion is happeing so i am thinking that auto incremented field could be issue. if do you feel same then can you please suggest me some way to fix this issue.

Comment: your solution work . db takes time to reflect inserted data :-)

Comment: @Nand Yes it can take time and also hibernate takes time to flush it too.. Glad it worked.. You can accept this answer if my solution worked.. :-)

Comment: @Nand yes we can !!  Just mention the stackoverflow refernce there so that it reminds me..

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to use session.save() instead of session.persist(), or you have to use flush at the end of transaction as pointed by Viraj, also refer this post

[What's the advantage of persist() vs save() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862680/whats-the-advantage-of-persist-vs-save-in-hibernate)

Comment: Hi pappu, I am using "session.persist" and also tested code provided by viraj that didn't work. I think issue with auto incremented field defined in table. Can you please show me some way to fix that.